# Google Developer Phone

Tags: android

Do I need google developer Phone to be an android developer?  If I purchase a phone from Rogers with Android OS, is that ok for me to write applications and try it out?  Let me know what is the best practice?

Answer (score 5):

You do need a phone, in my opinion, but you don't need developer phone to write applications.

One of the limitation you'll run into for example, not able to look at all files, and connect hierarchyviewer to see layouts for any app. Than again  you can always make it a developer phone.

Comment: How can I make it a developer phone?  It will be locked by the carrier?  May be I am too new to this and not following the answer properly.

Comment: Basically, get the phone from Rogers, if you run into limitations ( which i doubt ) - root it.  Alternative i think a lot of people selling used dev phones now. :)

Comment: Carrier lock has nothing to do with development. It means that you won't be able to use your device with another carrier SIM.

Comment: And finally, if you already considered spending close to 400$ on dev phone - just get yourself a treat and get NexusOne. Just make sure it works on Rogers frequencies

Comment: @Alex, thanks that's good suggestion.  Should I look at ebay for used cellphones?

Answer (score 3):

you can develop on the [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html), which comes with the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) no need to buy a phone...

Comment: One thing to note is that there are some limitations to the emulator. They can be found here. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#limitations

Comment: There is something to be said for having an actual device to test on.  The emulator suggestion is a good one, but you will eventually need a device to tune your application. Not sure if you require root privileges on a phone to develop for it.  I know the dev g1 came rooted when i bought it.

Comment: That's true but I would like to try the final app on a phone.  I think I need a phone but not sure if have to go with Google Developer phone or any phone with Android on it.  I can get a phone from Rogers but that will be locked.  Does that matter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the phone will be locked to rogers, but not for dev purposes

Comment: @Chris - one more too: no flashing LED indicator.  I still don't know why that's not on the list.

Comment: having a pysical device is great, but it's not strictly necessary for much development. most of the apps in the marketplace could be developed on an emulator without any problem. @naeem, the main diff would be the carrier might not always have the latest firmware rolled-out to their users, whereas w/the emulator or dev phone you can always have the latest OS

Comment: "@naeem, the main diff would be the carrier might not always have the latest firmware rolled-out to their users, whereas w/the dev phone you can always have the latest OS"

Thanks, that's correct.  I will be limited to the carrier's OS version.

Comment: I haven't registered as google developer.  May be I should start with that.  Is there only 1 dev phone with Google or are there choices? Also, does this phone have GPS, WiFi, proximity sensor, light senson, accelerometer, compass?

Comment: @naeem, i think it has all that except light/proximity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Dev_Phone#Android_Dev_Phone_2  http://android.brightstarcorp.com/index_adp2.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that you can develop with any phone. From the home screen you'll probably want to hit menu, go to setting and select Applications. From there Development. Under development you'll want to turn on USB debugging so you can run programs on your phone from inside Eclipse.

Comment: Also, "Allow non market applications" (or however it's worded).

Comment: You don't have to check allow non-market applications unless you plan on installing .apk files from the internet.  Only the USB debugging option needs to be selected to run your applications that are being pushed over from Eclipse.