# What would be a good Android tablet to buy to test code?

Tags: android, testing

I’m producing an Android app for a customer. Currently I do not have an Android device. Does any have any suggestions on what Android device I should get to test my code on a real device?

Could I just get a really cheap one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it worth purchasing Google Android Dev phone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964788/is-it-worth-purchasing-google-android-dev-phone)

Comment: Please search for an answer before posting.  This question has been covered many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964788/is-it-worth-purchasing-google-android-dev-phone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030536/google-developer-phone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539074/which-android-phone-to-use-for-development

Comment: tablet is different from phone... this is a valid question IMO (judged by the title)

Answer (score 2):

I bought a tablet for development testing and it has been INVALUABLE, so I definitely recommend others do it. In theory Android devices are pretty much all the same, but this isn't true in reality. As Android developers we do better if we have more than one device to test on - it's dangerous to assume "it works on my phone, it'll work ok on other devices" - NO.

I think you have three options:

1. Buy a very cheap tablet. It may not be approved by Google, so it may be missing some stuff, e.g. the Geolocation APIs, as well as GMail, Market etc. It may also not have a GPS, probably won't have 3G. This makes it a fairly bad tablet, but great for testing. I bought a cheap one and it's made it clear just how often Android apps blow up if they've not been tested on a device that's v different to a phone. I'm amazed how many apps don't use exception handling round a GPS lookup, so the app fails (including Tweetdeck).
2. Buy the Motorola XOOM. It's the first Google-approved tablet, and will be the first Honeycomb tablet. It looks like it'll be on sale in February. Probably $700-800 so not cheap, but it does look very promising as a device, and if you want to test against the presence of features (rather than absence) this is the one (until anything better comes).
3. Wait for a while and I suspect by the Spring the market will be flooded with tablets from many manufacturers, and prices may come down, with more choice.

I suppose another option is to not buy one, and let your users report bugs and request improvements, and rely on the emulator, but that's a poor approach.

I think if your customer needs the app to work well on tablets (you didn't say) then you must buy one, and if they're likely to buy XOOMs, you should get one of them. If it was me I'd want to know what devices the customer needs the app to run on, and get one of them.

I bought an Advent Vega (UK) for testing (a bit like the Viewsonic GTab) and it's great for testing, but when the XOOM arrives I expect I will buy one of them, as the experience of using it will be much better. The screen on the Vega is pretty bad.

Comment: Thank you.  I bought the Archos 7, only $150.  I set the device to debug, and it seems like the driver installs automatically.  I can’t figure out how to get my program to run in the device instead of the emulator.  Do you know of any EASY to follow toturtols

Comment: It may be a driver issue. Usually if you have a device plugged in via USB, the IDE will fire up the app on it; if there's no device present it starts the emulator. I suggest you check the right drivers are installed for the device and if that fails, search on here for an answer, and if no joy, post a new question. Do remember to rate answers you get and pick the best answer for each question.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best test device, but in terms of getting an android tablet cheaply, you may consider buying a Nook Color from Barnes & Noble, and rooting it.

http://blogkindle.com/2010/12/read-kindle-books-on-nook-color/

http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/nook-color-technical/3483-nookcolor-full-specifications.html

Comment: Project that take surveys.  The customer unit cost $400, the guy is repackaging Androids from china, for $50 each! what a savings!